# Jquery Mobile Select not updating to show value after options added

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple select box:

```
<select  id="collectorMainsInspEmissSelect">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

It has a default option that shows nothing and has no value.

Whenever a button is clicked:
`<a data-role="button"   style="padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; margin-top:8px;" id="collectorMainsInspAddEmissButton" onclick="main.CollectorMains.addEmiss()">Add Emiss</a>`

It runs this function:

```
function addEmiss() {

    var last = $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last-child").val();
    if ($.isNumeric(last)) {
        $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last").after("<option value=" + (parseInt(last) + 1) + ">" + (parseInt(last) + 1) + "</option>");
        $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last").prop('selected', true);
    }
    else {
        $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last").after("<option value=1>1</option>");
        $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect option:last").prop('selected', true);
    }
    console.log($("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect").val());
}
```

What this does is checks the last option in that select.  If it's blank, it makes a new option with a value and text of 1.  Otherwise, it adds a new option which was the previous option incremented.

That part works just fine.  New options are added.

Next, I have it set the value of the select to be the last option.  I want it to visually change the select box to show the last option, and I want the value to be that option as well.

In the background, the value is changing.  Visually, however, it is not.

I've got that `console.log` there to show that the value increases every time the button is clicked. 
Here's a jsfiddle of what I want it to do: https://jsfiddle.net/w5r93t3c/1/

You'll notice that it's working fine in the jsfiddle.  That's my problem, too.  I don't understand why the select isn't visually updating in my Jquery mobile application.  Do I need to somehow refresh the select?

Comment: Solved.  Added `$("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect").selectmenu('refresh', true);` at the end

Comment: You should post a formal answer to your question and accept it, not just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Added $("#collectorMainsInspEmissSelect").selectmenu('refresh', true); at the end